# Get value from Session or ViewState in AjaxFileUpload events from AjaxToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i'm trying to upload files by AjaxFileUpload, i have got it done. But now i need also to know 2 parameters, 1 is given on the URL adreess myPage.aspx?parameter=2

the second is in ViewState.

But on event OnUploadStart or OnUploadComplete

i dont have access to these values event when i tried session.

How can i solve this problem ??

Here is my ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AutoUpload.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoUpload" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValue"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSetValue" Text="set" OnClick="btnSetValue_OnClick"/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenValue"/>

    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload" MaximumNumberOfFiles="50" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"  OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_OnUploadComplete" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload_OnUploadStart" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my server side

```
     using System;
     using AjaxControlToolkit;

     public static class Validators
     {
          public static bool IsNumeric(this string value)
          {
               int myInt;
               bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(value, out myInt);
               return isNumerical;
          }
      }

public partial class AutoUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int Recid
    {
        get
        {
            if ((ViewState["Recid"] != null) && ((ViewState["Recid"].ToString()).IsNumeric()))
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Recid"]);
            return 0;
        }
        set { ViewState["Recid"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && id.IsNumeric())
            Recid = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    }

    protected void btnSetValue_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hiddenValue.Value = txtValue.Text.ToString();
    }


    protected void AjaxFileUpload_OnUploadStart(object sender, AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs e)
    {
        int myId = Recid; // THIS IS ALWAYS 0
        string otherValue = hiddenValue.Value;
    }

    protected void AjaxFileUpload_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        int myId = Recid; // THIS IS ALWAYS 0
        string otherValue = hiddenValue.Value;

        AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + e.FileName));
    }


}
```

If you try to run the aspx with parameter for example ?id=12 it should be stored in Recid, also the value from input field should be stored in hiddenValue.

But when i'm uploading files (event OnUploadStart or OnUploadComplete) i dont have access to these values, I also tried Session but it also didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

AjaxFileUpload does not preserve query string parameters in the latest released version 15.1.4 up to this moment.

However, you can download and compile the [source code](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) where this issue is already fixed and AjaxFileUpload keeps query string parameters.